# Find all the coordinates between two points (in 3d)

Tags: 3d, coordinates, points

```
Point 1: 0, 0, 0
Point 2: 10, 10, 3
```

What I need is to figure out how to get all the coordinates in between the two points so for example it would output

```
0, 0, 0
0, 0, 1
0, 0, 2
0, 0, 3
0, 1, 0
0, 1, 1
0, 1, 2
0, 1, 3
1, 0, 0
1, 1, 0
1, 0, 1
1, 1, 1
```

ect. ect... you get the point.. until you have EVERY coord between the two.

using java kindof so really any way of accomplishing this with math help me!

as you can see they will all be whole number no decimals so there are NOT an infinite amount of points.

Comment: You can not get every point between 2 points as there are an infinite amount of points between those 2 points. you need some sort of granularity.

Comment: Theres not an infinite number of points.. It's a video game and there are actually no decimals so only whole numbers in coords.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode:

```
for (x from p1.x to p2.x)
    for (y from p1.y to p2.y)
        for (z from p1.z to p2.z)
            new_point = (x, y, z) // do what you will with this
```

Make sure that when you convert the pseudocode to Java your `for`-loops will have steps being either +1 or -1 depending on whether `p1` or `p2` has the smaller coordinate, you will have to make this explicit.

Note however that although these points fit your problem description, they are not "between" the given `p1` and `p2`. As your example demonstrates, you will get a cube two of whose opposite corners are the given points. Maybe this is what you actually want?

If you discover that you actually want the points on or around the **line between** `p1` and `p2` then that is a harder problem (just because you want integers).